# Using fetch in chrome extension popup.js return empty response object

Tags: javascript, google-chrome, google-chrome-extension, fetch

Below is the code for the popup.js in my chrome extension v3
The parts I commented out are meant to extract previews (of the first few lines) for the respective queries, but when implemented, the search for the extension does not work at all (no errors though).

I tried logging into console to see what happened along the way, and noticed that even the response object did not register anything in the console, needless to say the HTML. Any clues, or perhaps there are better ways to generate the previews?

````
document.addEventListener("DOMContentLoaded", function () {
    // Select the search form and the search results container
    var form = document.getElementById("search-form");
    var container = document.getElementById("search-results");

    // Handle the submit event of the form
    form.addEventListener("submit", function (event) {
        event.preventDefault(); // Prevent the form from being submitted

        // Get the search title from the form
        var title = form.elements.title.value;
        var title2 = title.replace(/ /g, "+"); // Replace spaces with +
        var results = [];
        var queries = [
            {
                url: `https://www.ncbi.nlm.nih.gov/pmc/?term=${title}`,
                title: "NCBI PMC"
            },
            {
                url: `https://www.biorxiv.org/search/${title}`,
                title: "bioRxiv"
            },
            {
                url: `https://www.medrxiv.org/search/${title}`,
                title: "medRxiv"
            },
            {
                url: `https://www.google.com/search?q=${title2}+filetype:pdf`,
                title: "PDF Search"
            }
        ];
        queries.forEach(function (query) {
            fetch(query.url)
                .then(function (response) {
                    return response.text();
                    console.log(response);
                })
                // .then(function (html) {
                //     console.log(query.title);
                //     console.dir(html); // Inspect the properties of the html variable
                //     console.table(html); // View the contents of the html variable as a table
                //     // Parse the HTML using the DOMParser
                //     var parser = new DOMParser();
                //     var doc = parser.parseFromString(html, "text/html");
                //     // Extract the relevant information from the parsed HTML
                //     var title = doc.querySelector("title").innerText;
                //     var lines = [];
                //     var paragraphs = doc.querySelectorAll("p");
                //     for (var i = 0; i < paragraphs.length; i++) {
                //         lines.push(paragraphs[i].innerText);
                //         if (lines.length === 5) {
                //             break; // Break the loop
                //         }
                //     }
                    results.push({
                        title: query.title,
                        url: query.url,
                        // preview: lines.join("\n")
                    });
                // });
        });

        // Create the search results HTML
        var resultsHTML = "";
        results.forEach(function (result) {
            resultsHTML += `<div class="result">
        <h2><a href="#" data-url="${result.url}">${result.title}</a></h2>
        <p>${result.preview}</p>
      </div>`;
        });

        // Update the container with the search results HTML
        container.innerHTML = resultsHTML;

        // Handle the click event of the result links
        container.addEventListener("click", function (event) {
            var target = event.target;
            if (target.tagName === "A") {
                // Open the URL in a new tab and bring it to the front
                var url = target.dataset.url;
                var tab = window.open(url, "_blank");
                tab.focus();
            }
        });
    });
});```
````

Comment: Are you checking the right devtools console? I mean the console of popup?

Comment: 1) Make sure these URLs are covered by `host_permissions` in your manifest.json 2) Note that the popup is a separate window so it has its own separate devtools: right-click inside the popup and select "inspect" in the menu.

Comment: Thanks all, yes it's covered by my host_permissions, and it is in the console of the popup...

Comment: I do see the fetch successfully getting the results, but somehow if the `.then(function (html) {` part of the code was included the popup search no longer return results